# Boot repair enable a repository containing grub2 packages

Tags: grub2, repository, boot-repair

Got no Ubuntu 16.04 access after reinstalling Windows. I'm using Boot Repair with live USB version of Ubuntu 16.10. After clicking "Recommended repair" I got this message as shown in the below screenshot:

> Please enable a repository containing the [grub2] packages in the software sources of Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (sdb8). Then try again

Also two other windows pops up. How do I enable the correct repository?

[image: Screenshot of: Install software additionally or only from these sources?]

Comment: it is looking for 16.04 repos and you are using 16.10 ???? how did you install boot repair ?

Comment: @ bodhi.zazen With these commands on Ubuntu 16.04 live:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair   
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

Comment: What's the output of `lsb_release -a` and the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: I suggest you use the boot repair live image - https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

Comment: Which version of ubuntu do you have installed, and what version is the live image using? Also, are you connected to the internet (when running the `boot-repiar` command), and what is the output of `sudo apt-get install grub2`?

Comment: @Dawid Forester, `lsb_release -a` output: 
`No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:    yakkety`
and sources.list:
`deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.10 _Yakkety Yak_ - Release amd64 (20161012.2)]/ yakkety main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted`

Comment: @Wilf Output of `sudo apt-get install grub2` is:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package grub2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  grub-pc-bin grub-pc grub-ieee1275-bin grub-ieee1275 grub-efi-ia32-bin
  grub-efi-ia32 grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin
E: Package 'grub2' has no installation candidate
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$`

Comment: @ Wilf  Installed is 16.04, live image is 16.10. Yes, I'm connected to the Internet.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I've already tried it. No effect.

Answer (score 2):

Boot Repair didn't work work me. After a lot of searching and trying I finally managed to regain access to my Ubuntu with following set of commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb8 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev/
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sdb
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdb
update-grub
exit
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts
```

(All commands were executed in LiveUSB)