# Help with fixing boot-repair

Tags: 20.04, boot-repair

I followed recommended instructions on Boot Repair documentation but got an error saying Please enable a repository containing the [grub-efi-amd64-signed] packages in the software sources of unknown Linux distribution (sda5);

Then I followed the instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/936807/1200681) but I got stuck at the step 'sudo chroot /mnt' which returns the error "chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/bash’: Accessing a corrupted shared library".

There is the pastebin of my boot repair report. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dycxWG9nRh/

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20. It was initialising dial booting with my Windiows, but it is not working anymore when the / folder got filled up

Comment: There is no version 20 of Ubuntu. The 2 current versions are 20.04 and 20.10

Comment: 20.04 is the one I am using

Comment: You posted the error info but where is the information in the here and here you refereed to? How can anyone know what you did. *I followed instructions here and here and got the error

Comment: It seems the links were removed, Here are the details: I followed instructions on recommended repair from Boot Repair but I get an error saying  'Please enable a repository containing the [grub-efi-amd64-signed] packages in the software sources of unknown Linux distribution (sda5). Then try again. Then I tried a manual option, using the  instructions here (https://askubuntu.com/a/936807/1200681) editing according to my config but I got stuck at  'sudo chroot /mnt' which returns the error

"chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/bash’: Accessing a corrupted shared library"

Comment: Please add this info to the question so everyone can read them and edit your question.

Comment: I have made edits

Comment: You have Windows in UEFI boot mode, and installed Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode. Boot-Repair correctly suggested to re-install grub's UEFI version to convert install to UEFI boot mode. Best to have UEFI Secure boot off, network must be working, so Boot-Repair can download the correct grub version. It walks you thru a chroot to make fixes. If not using Boot-Repair UEFI chroot commands: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380

Comment: @oldfred I am still get stuck at the step for  chroot /mnt , it returns an error  "failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/bash’: Accessing a corrupted shared library"

Comment: @oldfred This is what my disk looks like in gparted https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-epgYOuf9TlK6OlKef4KXv_FoY3D9DKb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: did install ubuntu quite recently?

Comment: @nobody I installed a while back, I have een able to fix sda5 disk but ubuntu still not booting

Comment: @oldfred is right. but I would save data and reinstall the OS  anew in UEFI-mode.

Comment: With Ubuntu and good backups,with any fix that take more than a few hours, you will find a new install & restore from backups to be quicker. I have data in separate data partition so rarely have to restore it. But have a new install in 10 minutes from loading in RAM to SSD, updates using script files another 20 minutes. Very little I restore from /home. A full restore of all my data using rsync, if required may take another 20 minutes.